# Построение гистограммы в С++ Builder

Tags: c, c++builder

Суть моей проблемы. Есть текстовый файл, который содержит информацию о проходившем трафике вида 127.0.0.1(источник) 192.168.0.1(назначение) 5(кол-во пакетов). Я хочу построить график зависимости количества адресов(допустим 127.0.0.1) от времени.
У меня получилось достать адреса,но вот как по ним построить зависимость не пойму, пробовал строить графики в C++ Builder для других функций вроде разобрался, а для своей задачи нет. Может информацию из файла нужно представить в матричном виде или как то по другому представить?? но тогда как? подскажите

```
int main(void)
{
    int i,k = 0;
    int j = 1;
    char buffer0[30];//задаю массив куда будут помещаться строки из файла
    FILE *fi;
    fi = fopen(OUTPUTFILE,"rt");
    printf("\n\n\t\tSource address\n\n");
    while (!feof(fi)){
            fscanf(fi,"%s\n",buffer0);//построчно помещаю в буфер строки
            i++;
            while (i == j){
                if (buffer0[k] == '1' && buffer0[k+1] == '2' && buffer0[k+2] == '7')//задаю условие, чтобы выводил только адреса вида 127.
                printf("%23s\n",buffer0);
                j += 8;
                }
            }

    fclose(fi);
    return 0;
}}
```

Comment: Гистограмма, наверное, вам нужна.

Comment: Думаю стоит поправить заголовок, т.к. я не вижу проблемы непосредственно в работе с файлами.

Comment: Изменил)) Думаю так точнее

Comment: Судя по вашему описанию, у вас есть информация только об адресах и количестве пакетов, а зависимость вы хотите строить от времени... Но ведь у вас, похоже, просто нет нужной информации?

Comment: Действительно...Даже не задумывался, ну тогда скорректирую вопрос, как построить гистограмму не от времени, а от количества пакетов??